# add array to array in array - objC

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

Man,just like the topic above if i want to make change directly with an exiting mutable array.
i want to know how to add a new array to an exiting array in a mutable array
Thanks for any advise!

Comment: Please elaborate your question little more

Answer (score 1):

The problem which you mentioned to add an array into another array which is contained in the NSMutableArray, it can be done like

```
NSMutableArray *childArray = [self.ParentArray objectAtIndex:index];
[childArray addObjectsFromArray:yourArrayToAdd];
```

hope that will solve your problem

Comment: NSMutablearray *arrayOne=[[nsmutablearray alloc]init]; NSMutablearray *arrayMain=[[nsmutablearray alloc]init]; [arrayMain addObject:arrayOne]; NSMutableArray *temp = [arrayMain objectAtIndex:yourIndex]; [temp addObject:yourNextArray];

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have an `NSMutableArray` named `numbersArray`

```
numbersArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7",@"8",@"9",@"10" , nil];
```

if you want to add an array to it instead of the original, lets say that array is an random array of its own content:

```
NSMutableArray *temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:numbersArray];

for(NSUInteger i = [numbersArray count]; i > 1; i--) {
    NSUInteger j = arc4random_uniform(i);
    [temp exchangeObjectAtIndex:i-1 withObjectAtIndex:j];
}
numbersArray = temp;
```

the last line give the `numbersArray` the content of the `temp` array

and we can do that with

```
numbersArray = [temp copy];
```

for the index exchange you can use `exchangeObjectAtIndex` as follow:

```
[numbersArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:0 withObjectAtIndex:3];
[numbersArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:1 withObjectAtIndex:4];
[numbersArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:2 withObjectAtIndex:5];
```